# Dimmer light switch - smell & yellow foam

Tags: dimmer-switch

A tenant reported flickering batheroom LED lights on a dimmer switch. Dimmer was making crackling sound, hot and smell. They disabled mains to prevent any further issue. Opening the dimmer case is a yellow foam which has hardened (pictured).  What is this, can it be safely removed and a new switch installed?

I assume it's faulty dimmer switch the cause, but online searches never seem to suggest this possibility, and all tend to suggest the wrong dimmer switch / LED pairings (was working fine till recently).

Thanks
J

[image: Dimmer Switch yellow foam]

Comment: I *suspect* that yellow foam was added in an ill-advised attempt to prevent air leakage. When (a) foam is not normally added *inside* an electrical box, and in fact would be quite dangerous to do so in the event of sparks/arcing/overheating, all of which are supposed to be contained by the box and (b) the place to put foam, especially spray/expandable foam, to prevent air leaks is *around* the box - i.e., outside the box and inside the wall cavity.

Comment: The foam looks like the common spray gap insulation stuff.  Filling an electrical switch/outlet box is not what it should be used for.  Not enough picture to tell if the dimmer is mounted with screws, as it should be, or someone used the foam for mounting, a no-no.  As it is a rental place, a licensed electrician is required for the work.

Comment: Dimmers tend to make a bit more heat than other switches, so with that foam someone made a tiny oven, which the dimmer did not like.

Answer (score 3):

Ever hear of Grenfell Towers?

That stuff there is cheap, 1-part "spray foam in a can".  That stuff has extremely terrible fire characteristics, and is not far removed from napalm.  (There is an alternate, 2-part style that mixes like epoxy using special machinery on-site; with that stuff *it is possible* to have better fire characteristics (but not guaranteed).

Dimmers make heat and need to cool. If they don't cool they overheat.  Foaming one in so it cannot cool, and gets quite hot, is a bad idea.  Using napalm is a much worse idea.

I would pull mains power to the building and search multiple units for this, and remove it entirely from all junction boxes. Search other rental units so you don't accidentally blame a tenant for something a contractor did.

If you can put it on a particular tenant, I would ask them to pay for its careful removal from each box, to be done by a professional.   I suspect DIY work by a tenant because landlords don't pay heating bills or care how drafty it is.

Comment: Unless it is first tenant of the apartment or a very long-term tenant, can't blame it on the current tenant - could be any previous tenant and unless one left in the last year it would be ridiculous to chase them down (and unless that tenant was the first tenant, can't prove much anyway).